# How can I link a numbered bullet point to a sentence that references that bullet point and changes whenever the bullet point does?

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets

I have a list of procedures such as

1. Do this
2. Do that
3. Do the same thing as done in step 2, but differently
4. Do some more of this
5. Wave that over there

In this example I have one bullet point referenced in another bullet point. Step 2 is referenced in Step 3.

How can I link the "step 2" in Step 3 so that if the numbering on Step 2 were to change, it would also change the "step 2" to follow.

For instance, if I realize I forgot a step and insert it into the beginning of my list of procedures, I would like "links" to update as well.

1. Start the thing
2. Do this
3. Do that
4. Do that same thing as step 3 but differently
5. Do some more of this
6. Wave that over there

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, just use cross-references (on the References tab, Cross-reference button).

In the dialog box that pops up, ensure Reference type is "Numbered item", and Insert reference to "Paragraph number" (you can use any of the 3 paragraph number options, I use "Paragraph number (full context)").

If you have list numbering or outline numbering applied, you'll see your list of steps and text in the "For which numbered item" listbox.  Just click on the step you want to refer back to, and click Insert, then Close to return to the document.

A field will have been inserted (if you have your Options set to show shading always you'll see it as the number with a grey shaded field background).

To update, when you have finished editing your document, select all (ctrl a) and then press F9 (to update all fields - which includes cross-refereces and TOCs - in your document).  So if you have inserted a new step above (eg Step 3), the cross-reference fields to the old Step 3 should now say 4.